# Holder's inequality in the case of $L_1$ and $L_{\infty}$ norm

Tags: probability, probability-inequalities, measure-theory, inequality

I am referring to Wainwright's High-Dimensional Statistics book, where at some point it is deduced that
\begin{equation}
\frac{w'X\Delta}{n}\leq \left\lVert\frac{w'X}{n}\right\rVert_{\infty}\lVert\Delta\rVert_1
\end{equation}
due to Holder's inequality. In the above relationship, $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$ is a random design matrix, $w\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is an $n\times 1$ vector of errors and $\Delta:=\hat{\theta}-\theta^*$ where $\theta^*$ is the true parameter vector in the relationship
\begin{equation}
y=X\theta+w
\end{equation}
My question as follows: shouldn't there be an absolute value operator on the left hand side of the inequality?

Comment: It's hard to tell in the absence of any context about the application, because this inequality is true: removing the absolute value create the possibility the left hand side is negative, but then the inequality is trivial.

Comment: Could you also give a page number reference for this, because I know Wainwright does a computation like this in the proof of LASSO prediction error bounds but in my copy of the book (2019) there are absolute values. Of course, as whuber notes above adding the absolute values on the left-hand side is actually a weaker inequality since the negative case holds trivially.

Comment: @Ariel I am referring to page 212 of Wainright (2019), the second paragraph of the proof.